# Find the number of ways of distributing 15 chocolates among 3 kids where none gets less than 3 and more than 6.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Find the number of ways of distributing $15$ chocolates among $3$ kids where none gets less than $3$ and more than $6$.

Now, $a+3+b+3+c+3 = 15$.  $a+b+c=6$. Number of ways of distribution $= (6+3-1) C (3-1) =8C2$. We have to subtract the cases where $a>6$, $b>6$ & $c>6$. This part is my doubt.

Comment: Your question is tantamount to solving $x_1+x_2+x_3=15$, where $6\ge x_i\ge 3$.

Comment: Hint:  once you give them each three, you have $6$ left, and the only condition is that nobody get more than three of those.

Comment: Yes now a+3+b+3+c+3 =15
a+b+c=6
number of ways of distribution= (6+3-1) C (3-1) =8C2

We have to subtract the cases where a>6, b>6 & c>6 , this part is my doubt

Comment: I copied your work on the problem into the statement of your question.  When you pose a problem here, you should include your attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_k$ be the number of chocolates given to the $k$th child.  Then the number of ways of distributing the chocolates to the children given the restrictions that each child receives at least three and at most six chocolates is the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 6 \tag{1}$$
in the integers subject to the restrictions that $3 \leq x_k \leq 6$ for $1 \leq k \leq 3$.  Let $y_k = x_k - 3$ for $1 \leq k \leq 3$.  Then each $y_k$ is a non-negative integer such that $y_k \leq 3$.  Substituting $y_k + 3$ for $x_k$, $1 \leq k \leq 3$, in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
y_1 + 3 + y_2 + 3 + y_3 + 3 & = 15\\
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 & = 6 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the non-negative integers.  A particular solution corresponds to the placement of two addition signs in a row of six ones.  For instance, 
$$1 1 1 1 + + 1 1$$
corresponds to the (excluded) solution $y_1 = 4$, $y_2 = 0$, $y_3 = 2$, while 
$$1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1$$
corresponds to the solution $y_1 = 2$, $y_2 = 3$, $y_3 = 1$.  Thus, the number of solutions of equation 2 is the number of ways two addition signs can be inserted into a row of six ones, which is
$$\binom{6 + 2}{2} = \binom{8}{2}$$
since we must choose which two of the eight symbols (six ones and two addition signs) will be addition signs.

However, these solutions include those in which one or more of the $y_k$'s exceeds $3$.  Since $2 \cdot 4 = 8 > 6$, at most one of the $y_k$'s can exceed $3$.  Suppose $y_1 > 3$.  Let $z_1 = y_1 - 4$.  Then $z_1$ is a non-negative integer.  Substituting $z_1 + 4$ for $y_1$ in equation 2 yields
\begin{align*}
z_1 + 4 + y_2 + y_3 & = 6\\
z_1 + y_2 + y_3 & = 2 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Equation 3 is an equation in the non-negative integers with $\binom{2 + 2}{2} = \binom{4}{2}$ solutions.  By symmetry, there are also $\binom{4}{2}$ solutions in which $y_2 > 3$ or $y_3 > 3$.  Thus, the number of solutions in which one of the $y_k$'s exceeds $3$ is 
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{2}$$
Hence, the number of ways of distributing the chocolates to the three children so that each child receives at least three chocolates and at most six chocolates is 
$$\binom{8}{2} - \binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{2}$$
which is a small enough number that you can check the result by simply listing the possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Following the idea in Lulu's comment,  you can first give each kid 3 chocolates and then count the number of ways to distribute the remaining 6 chocolates.

Since nobody can get more than 3 additional chocolates, we have 3 cases to consider:

1) Each child gets 2 chocolates, which gives 1 possibility.

2) Two kids get 3 chocolates, and the other gets none, which gives 3 possibilities.

3) One kid gets 3 chocolates, another gets 2, and the last kid gets 1, which gives $3\cdot2\cdot1=6$ possibilities.

Thus there are 10 possible ways to do this.